# All about estimators biased and unbiased

Tags: probability, probability-theory, estimation

I am unable to understand the difference between an estimator and a distribution, for example what is the difference between variance of a distribution and the variance of an estimator, and what is relation between them.

Suppose I can sample $X$ from distribution $D$, and I need to find a `good` estimate $f(x)$. What kind of an estimator should I use?

I would also like to know about a good resource that discusses estimators in detail.

Comment: Any random variable has a variance. So any estimator has a variance (on the other hand, we tend to identify probability measures with random variables)

Comment: Think about the basic example:  a variable attached to a population.  The population mean is some number.  It hasn't got a variance or a distribution, even though you don't know what the number is.  Now, you estimate it, say by using a sample from the population.  That sampled number is an estimator which, presumably, has a distribution (that is, a different sample might well return a different sample mean).

Comment: What is a `good` estimator depends on the application context (e.g., robustness vs efficiency).  Probably better suited for stats SE.

Comment: is there any procedure for computing the variance of an estimator? Any equation/algorithm to do so?

Comment: @AJ unfortunately, no

Comment: Is there any online lecture series or resource that talks about estimations and their related quantities/measures?